# Client-to-client communication not working on AWS Lightsail Debian Linux OpenVPN server

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, ssh, openvpn, amazon-lightsail

I have an AWS Lightsail Server running Linux Debian 10. I have set up an OpenVPN server on the AWS server. I want to be able to allow client-to-client communication, but have been unsuccessful in even getting a ping between two clients (client1-rpi RaspberryPi OS, client2-Mac OSX Montery). I will label the following IP's with variables to avoid confusion:

Static Public IP for AWS toward Internet: x.x.x.x

LAN IP for AWS Server: y.y.y.y

OpenVPN default Server IP: z.z.z.z (10.8.0.1)

VPN Port: PPPP

Below are my current configs with pertinent numbers changed out:
server.conf:

```
port PPPP 
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server z.z.z.z 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_.crt
key server_.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3

client-to-client
push "route z.z.z.z 255.255.255.0"
```

client1.ovpn/client2.ovpn:

```
client
proto udp
explicit-exit-notify
remote x.x.x.x PPPP
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_ name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CERTIFICATE INFO
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CERTIFICATE INFO
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
CERTIFICATE INFO
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-crypt>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
CERTIFICATE INFO
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-crypt>
```

ccd file (client1):

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.0
push "route-gateway 10.8.0.1"
```

ccd file (client2):

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.0
push "route-gateway 10.8.0.1"
```

So at this point, I've tried routing the iptables. Though I've really just copied and pasted what some [this article](http://backreference.org/2010/05/02/controlling-client-to-client-connections-in-openvpn/) said would work. I can get both clients connected and was able to test the internet connection through the vpn by checking my public IP on the Mac (it matched the x.x.x.x). I was able to get internet. I successfully get the desired IP address assigned to the client, I can ping 10.8.0.1, but I can't ping the other client.

I have spent several hours looking up people with similar problems and attempting to replicate their fixes, but I am unsure what to do at this point. No matter what I do, I get the same following error when pinging:

```
PING 10.8.0.2 (10.8.0.2): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
```

I would like to be able to not only ping, but hopefully ssh from client2 to client1. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

I understand this is coming from a huge gap in understanding on my part and would not mind any education this community could provide me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was reading my post and realized something. In my ccd files, I did not put a subnet mask after the route IP address. I added the subnet mask and now I can ping and ssh between clients. My ccd files look like this now:

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.z 255.255.255.0
push "route-gateway 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.0"
```